# Calculating time

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create an app on RoR that calculates time.

when you press as start button it will pull Time.now, then, when you press stop and will pull Time.now again and then calculate the amount of time between the two. Then it will convert the seconds given into and integer via to_i and then calculate the seconds integer into hours:minutes:seconds

However something is up with my code it keeps throwing error after error.

the current order is "undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass"

```
def create
  @start_time = Time.now
end 

def destroy
  @stop_time = Time.now
end 

def show
  @total_time = hours_worked(total_time)
end 

private

def total_time
  total_time = @stop_time - @start_time
  return total_time.to_i
end 

def time_worked(seconds_worked)
  hours = seconds_worked / ( 60 * 60 )
  minutes = ( seconds_worked / 60 ) % 60
  seconds = seconds_worked % 60
  return "#{hours} + “:” + #{minutes} + “:” + #{seconds}"
end
```

Comment: You're calling the `-` method on `nil`, like the error says. Since the only place you're calling `-` is in the `total_time` method, it follows that `@stop_time` is `nil`.

Comment: I would consider renaming `hours_worked` to `time_worked`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your underlying problem is that you're assuming your instance variables (`@start_time` and `@stop_time`) persist across requests. They don't. Each time you hit one of these endpoints, you're dealing with an entirely new instance of the controller, so even if you've called `#create` and `#destroy` previously, when you call `#show`, both `@start_time` and `@stop_time` are `nil`.

If you do want data to persist across requests, you need some kind of persistence mechanism in place, i.e. a database or key-value store. Instance variables are only held in memory for the duration of a single request/response cycle.

Answer (score 1):

The only place where `-` is called is in your `total_time` method. Since it says "NoMethod - for nil class" that means that the variable before the minus sign is undefined. So here, that is the `@stop_time` variable.

It looks like `@stop_time` only gets defined when you call `create`. If you want your code to work, you'll have to call both `create` and `destroy` before calling `total_time`.

I'd bet that you're running them out of order - calling `total_time` before the others - and that's why you're getting an error.